# Google Apps Script - send email automatically from spreadsheet on shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

[Edited]

I'm using Apps Script in Sheets to use info from a form to, when the form is submitted, populate a template, create a PDF file, and then automatically email the PDF to an email address created from information on the form. The form, the spreadsheet, and the template in a folder on a shared drive.

I get the following error: "Exception: Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item" at *tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile)*. When I deactivate that line of code the script works perfectly. I assume it has something to do with permissions on a shared drive, but am not sure how to set it up to allow me to delete that temporary file. I'm very new to coding, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Here is my script:

```
  
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  var caseEmail = e.namedValues['LegalServer Case Number']+"@fls.legalserver.org";

  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("With Links");

  ws.getRange(entryRow,8).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  ws.getRange(entryRow,7).setValue(pdfFile.getName());

  sendEmail(caseEmail, pdfFile);
 
 
  
}

function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Screening Form","Screening Form Attached",{
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Info'
  });
}

function createPDF(info){

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("idforpdffolder");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("idfortempdocfolder");
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("idfortemplate");

var caseEmail = info['CaseNumber'][0]+"@email.org";

const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();


  body.replaceText("{casenumber}", info['CaseNumber'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{name}", info['Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{timestamp}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
  
  body.replaceText("{casemail}", caseEmail);
     //(others deleted for space)


openDoc.saveAndClose();





const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name'][0]+" - " +info['Timestamp'][0]);
**tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);**

return pdfFile;




}
```

Comment: Where does the error of `Exception: Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item.` occur in your script? And, unfortunately, your showing script is incomplete. Can you provide your whole script?

Comment: @Tanaike It's happening at the second-to-last line (remove newTempFile). I updated the code. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From `It's happening at the second-to-last line (remove newTempFile). I updated the code. Thanks for looking at it.` and your updated question, if you want to remove the file of `newTempFile`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
```

#### To:

```
newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
```

- By this, the file of `newTempFile` is moved into the trash box.
- If you want to completely delete it, it is required to use Drive API as follows. But, in this case, it is required to enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) And, if you have no permission for writing in the shared Drive, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

  ```
    Drive.Files.remove(newTempFile.getId(), {supportsAllDrives: true})
  ```

#### Reference:

- [setTrashed(trashed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)